# $.ajax, complete function (no more data to get)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im new to .ajax and so far so good.  But I've run into an issue of, I want to run a function once I've used up all the data.

For example I have the following, i run it on 'click':

```
$.ajax({
        url: "url.modal.tothegoods" + (nextPage),
        success: function (data) {
             //keeps appending data on click
        },
        error: function () {
                alert('balls');
        }

 })
```

I've tried the ajaxcomplete function but it runs everytime i load data onto the screen.

It runs everytime i appened data .ajaxcomplete runs.  I guess the questions is, how do I run a function once I have no more data to consume.  So I am truly done

any tips/tricks would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I have no idea what the actual question is. What does "used up all the data" mean?

Comment: on click i run an ajaxcall, it loads more articles onto the page.   Im looking to run a seperate function once i've loaded all the articles there are to load. (so i've basically run out of information to load, run a function)

Comment: So the server should tell you when it is up.... And than you stop making calls and disable what ever you need to disable.

Answer (score 0):

The response depends on which is currently the behaviour of your server part.

If you have hand on it, the most simple solution is that it returns nothing when there is no more data to send. So you may do something as simple as this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "url.modal.tothegoods" + (nextPage),
        success: function (data) {
             if (!!data) {
             //keeps appending data on click
             }
        },
        error: function () {
                alert('balls');
        }

})
```

Comment: in your if(!!data) {}, would i then just put an else statement after to have my function for when there is no more data to use?

Comment: No, you must simply do the job to add the current `data` returned, at the place of the current `//keeps appending data on click`. Each time `$.ajax` works, it makes the server only return **one** piece of data, no? And there will be a time the server will not return anything at all. Point.

Comment: Hey @cFreed,  so the webservice continues to call pages even if the data runs out (call empty pages, so nothing get appened).  I think im asking the wrong question as the service is still called but its pages are empty eventually.

Comment: I suspect something wrong in the **general** strategy you're using.From what you posted, we can guess you launch your `$.ajax({...})` each time the user clicks some button to ask for a next page. So this Ajax request asks the server to return that next page (only 1 page!). It's up to it to know which page it already served, so there will be a time when it has no more page to serve and it will return nothing.